# UIPopOver management and USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME error

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopover

I've recently upgraded to iOS 6 Beta and am having some issues. (I know it's a beta, but I'm not yet convinced that it's actually iOS 6-related.)

The issue has the following parameters:

1. Custom `UITableViewCell` with `UIButton` objects that generate `UIPopOver` objects, presented from the frame of the `UIButton` that was tapped.
2. The `UIPopOver` is displayed and then the iPad is rotated.
3. My view dismisses the `UIPopOver` when the rotation animation completes and then re-displays the `UIPopOver`.

Relevant Information:

1. The first rotation proceeds fine; the `UIPopOver` is dismissed and re-displayed correctly.
2. The second rotation (EVERY TIME) is what breaks the app.
3. I have a symbolic breakpoint set, but I'm not getting any useful information.
4. I'm doing the same thing with `UIPopOver` objects presented from `UIBarButton` objects in a `UIToolbar`. I experience no problems with those transitions.
5. This is a new problem that is related to code that hasn't changed in a good while.
6. The error I receive is: "warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame."

Here's the code that executes related to the rotation:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if ([self PopOver]) {
        [[self PopOver] dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [self setPopOver:nil];
        [self ButtonPressed:[self TouchedCell]];
    }
    [[self TableView1] reloadData];
    [[self TableView2] reloadData];
}

- (void)ButtonPressed:(Cell *)cell {
    [self setTouchedCell:cell];
    NSString *nibName = @"View";
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        nibName = @"View-iPad";
    }

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName
                                                          bundle:nil];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UIPopoverController *popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
            initWithContentViewController:vc];
        [self setPopOver:popOver];
        [popOver setDelegate:self];
        [[self PopOver] setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320)];
        [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:[[cell CheckButton] frame] 
                                 inView:[cell contentView]
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                               animated:YES];
    } else {
        // iPhone doesn't use PopOvers...
    }
}
```

Anyone know what I should do next?

Comment: Has the cell you are trying to present the popover from moved off a screen after the table is reloaded?

Comment: I'll have to check again, but I don't believe that to be the case in the specific testing I've done. If I do a `[tableView reloadData]`, wouldn't that mean that any reference I have to a `UITableViewCell` ***might*** be invalid? I bet I'm trying to present it from a (now) non-existent cell. I'll check into that and THANKS FOR GETTING ME THINKING DOWN THE RIGHT PATH!!!

Comment: @JerryJones If you'll leave your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. It wasn't exactly what solved it for me, but it was close enough to get me to the right answer (apparently, I was trying to show a PopOver from an already-recycled UITableViewCell). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my official answer - I think your popover is trying to display offscreen, or maybe from an already recycled cell. ;)